# msqli prepared query not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `article_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `comment` VALUES (0,'Bernard','user@domain.com','This is a comment',1,'2014-07-22 17:34:24',0);
```

This php code spits out "foo" and nothing else:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo 'foo';
$db = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', '', 'ggs');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `comment` `c` WHERE `c`.`article_id` = ? AND `c`.`deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `c`.`date` ASC");
if (!$query) {
    echo $db->errno . " - Could not prepare SQL statement: " . $db->error;
} else {
    $query->bind_param('i', 1);
    $query->execute();
    echo json_encode($query->fetch());
}
echo 'bar';
```

Why is this failing, and why is it not throwing any errors?

Comment: After having put echo statements between every single line, it seems that it's simply stopping at: 
$query->bind_param('i', 1);

Comment: Does it stop before that line, or after? Could you try echoing `$query->error` after the binding, and see what you get?

Comment: changed it to:
echo "baz";
if (!$query->bind_param('i', 1)) {
  echo "fook";
  echo $query->errno . " - " . $query->error;
}
"baz" is the last thing I see.

Comment: What about `if ($query->bind_param('i', 1)) { echo 'foo'; } else { echo $query->error; }`? That should either print foo if it works, or give you an error message

Comment: no, it does not get past the if statement.  "baz" is the last thing echoed out.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($query)`, just after your prepare call?

Comment: object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) {
  ["affected_rows"] => int(0)
  ["insert_id"] => int(0)
  ["num_rows"] => int(0)
  ["param_count"] => int(1)
  ["field_count"] => int(7)
  ["errno"] => int(0)
  ["error"] => string(0) ""
  ["error_list"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["sqlstate"] => string(5) "00000"
  ["id"] => int(1)
}

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss. I can't see what the issue might be; I'd suggest losing the WHERE clause for the time being, and seeing what happens. Then add in your `deleted=0` part, and try again; then hard-wire `1` in for your article_id. That might at least give an idea why it's failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57787/discussion-between-bernard-lechler-and-andrewsi).

Comment: anything in your error log?

Answer (score 0):

As for the query, you should replace the first 0 a null to let the auto-increment work:

```
INSERT INTO `comment` VALUES (NULL,'Bernard','user@domain.com','This is a comment',1,'2014-07-22 17:34:24',0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a copy-paste from a mysql dump.